# Custom loss function for out of distribution detection using CNN in Tensorflow 2.0+

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

My question is in reference to the paper [Learning Confidence for Out-of-Distribution Detection in Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.04865).

I need help in creating a custom loss function in tensorflow 2.0+ as per the paper to get confident prediction from the CNN on a in distribution (if the image belongs to train categories) image while a low prediction for an out of distribution (any random image) image. The paper suggests adding a confidence estimation branch to any conventional feedforward architecture in parallel with the original class prediction branch (refer to image below)

[image]

In order to define the loss function, the softmax prediction probabilities are adjusted by interpolating between the original predictions(pi) and the target probability distribution y, where the degree of interpolation is indicated by the network’s confidence(c):

pi'= c · pi + (1 − c)yi and the final loss is :

[image]

I need help in implementing this along with the loss function in Tensorflow 2.0+, below is what I could think of, from my knowledge:

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as k
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50

#Defining custom loss function
def custom_loss(c):
  def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    interpolated_p = c*y_pred+ (1-c)*y_true
    return -k.reduce_sum((k.log(interpolated_p) * y_true), axis=-1) - k.log(c)
  return loss

#Defining model strcuture using resnet50
basemodel = ResNet50(weights = "imagenet",include_top = False)
headmodel = basemodel.output
headmodel = layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size = (7,7))(headmodel)

#Add a sigmoid layer to the pooling output
conf_branch = layers.Dense(1,activation = "sigmoid",name = "confidence_branch")(headmodel)

# Add a softmax layer after the pooling output 
softmax_branch = layers.Dense(10,activation = "softmax",name = "softmax_branch")(headmodel)

# Instantiate an end-to-end model predicting both confidence and class prediction
model = keras.Model(
    inputs=basemodel.input,
    outputs=[softmax_branch, conf_branch],
)

model.compile(loss=custom_loss(c=conf_branch.output), optimizer='rmsprop')
```

Appreciate any help on this ! Thanks !

Comment: Can you help us by clarifying what you are looking for? It seems you already have everything you need. Are you looking for a function to predict confidence? You don't know how to implement something? Also, if you want code, it would be helpful to show yours, for this question it would be useful to show your current loss function.

Comment: @Sorin:I have updated the question along with the code, have a look. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The following is the code I wrote for the keras implementation:

```
num_classes = 10
basemodel = ResNet50(weights = "imagenet",include_top = False)
headmodel = basemodel.output
headmodel = layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size = (7,7))(headmodel)
conf_branch = layers.Dense(1,activation = "sigmoid",name="confidence_branch")(headmodel)
softmax_branch = layers.Dense(num_classes,activation = "softmax",name = "softmax_branch")(headmodel)
output = Concatenate(axis=-1)([softmax_branch , conf_branch])

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred, budget=0.3):
    with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope("LAMBDA", reuse=tf.compat.v1.AUTO_REUSE):
        LAMBDA = tf.compat.v1.get_variable("LAMBDA", dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.constant(0.1))
    pred_original = y_pred[:, 0:num_classes]
    confidence = y_pred[:, num_classes]
    eps = 1e-12
    pred_original = tf.clip_by_value(pred_original, 0. + eps, 1. - eps)
    confidence = tf.clip_by_value(confidence, 0. + eps, 1. - eps)
    b = np.random.uniform(size=y_true.shape[0], low=0.0, high=1.0)
    conf = confidence * b + (1 - b)
    conf = tf.expand_dims(conf, axis=-1)
    pred_new = pred_original * conf + y_true * (1 - conf)
    xentropy_loss = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_true * tf.math.log(pred_new), axis=-1))
    confidence_loss = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.math.log(confidence))
    total_loss = xentropy_loss + LAMBDA * confidence_loss

    def true_func():
        return LAMBDA / 1.01

    def false_func():
        return LAMBDA / 0.99

    LAMBDA_NEW = tf.cond(budget > confidence_loss, true_func, false_func)
    LAMBDA.assign(LAMBDA_NEW)
    # tf.print(LAMBDA)
    return total_loss

def accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = y_pred[:, :num_classes]
    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_pred, 1), tf.argmax(y_true, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
    return accuracy

model = Model(inputs=basemodel.input, outputs=output)
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[accuracy])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).